# update password only if it is entered while updating user in Django admin

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I have custom user in Django, so in user creation form in admin we have `password` field, and its getting saved while creation, but when I go to change existing user and I am not entering/changing  password field , but it getting reflected in database. below is my code

```
class ChangeClientEmployeeMasterForm(forms.ModelForm):
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ChangeClientEmployeeMasterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['groups'].label='Roles'        
    if 'instance' in kwargs and hasattr(kwargs['instance'], 'client_employee_id'):
        self.client_employee_id = kwargs['instance'].client_employee_id
 def clean(self):
    if self.cleaned_data['client_employee_type'] =='imast':
        self.cleaned_data['is_superuser'] = True
    else :
        self.cleaned_data['is_superuser'] = False
    return self.cleaned_data
 def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(ChangeClientEmployeeMasterForm, self).save(commit=False)
    password = self.cleaned_data["password"]
    if password:
        user.set_password(password)
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
 class Meta:
    model = ClientEmployeeMaster
```

Comment: When you try to change existing user, I guess the `password` field is getting filled with existing password and so your condition is getting executed in save method. I would suggest to make the password blank when loading the form while updating.

Comment: yes..  password field is blank when I am loading the form, but still it is same

Comment: Don't you have Id for each user(which get created at the time of user creation)?. If so then whenever you fetch data to update then check if particular request comes with existing Id then just update the other details rather than password.

Comment: ok.. how can I update limited fields only, because I tried with model.save( update_fields=["my_fields"])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try this option, I tried this in Django Admin 1.10. This should work.

```
def clean(self):
    password = self.cleaned_data['password']
    if not password and password =='':
        del self.cleaned_data['password']
     #Add your extra code / statement here, if you need.
    return self.cleaned_data
```